# How can I get KendoUI to function while adhering to strict Content Security Policy for script-src

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, content-security-policy

I have a large web application, and I have come across an issue while attempting to implement Content Security Policy. I have created a very basic page for the sake of reproduction as described below. KendoUI fails off the bat. I have narrowed this down to being a CSP issue, specifically KendoUI runs fine when 'unsafe-eval' is enabled but not when it is disallowed, of course this is a serious concern so I am wondering if I may be using the wrong build or am missing something?

Rough demo demonstrating issue (header value is inserted via meta tag):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://cdn.kendostatic.com https://code.jquery.com;">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.3.930/js/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>See CSP Error in console</h1>
</body>
```

I get the CSP error using this header:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https://cdn.kendostatic.com https://code.jquery.com;
```

As soon as I add "unsafe-eval" to script-src options, the error goes away, however this seems unacceptable and likely to be a common issue as kendoui is such a widely used framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through further dialog with Telerik, I have been given the following response:

> Kendo UI uses eval() calls internally. This is how the Kendo UI templates work internally. Currently we do not have a workaround, but we are in a process of exploring new ways for rendering of the Kendo UI widgets, which will comply with this policy as well.